# All the values are fetched instead of selected value in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

I have a drop down with list of values. I take only the selected value from it with below code. It was working before and i know this is the correct way. But now my test returns all the dropdown values in return. I am not sure what is going on. Can any one help me?

```
@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "selected-borrower")
public static WebElement BorrowerName;

Select select = new Select(BorrowerName);
select.selectByVisibleText(borrFullName);
String ActBorrName = BorrowerName.getText();
System.out.println("ActBorrName: " + ActBorrName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the correct way to get the selected option is with `getFirstSelectedOption()`. `BorrowerName.getText()` will return the text of the `<select>` tag

```
@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "selected-borrower")
public static WebElement borrowerName;

Select select = new Select(borrowerName);
select.selectByVisibleText(borrFullName);
String actBorrName = select.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
System.out.println("ActBorrName: " + actBorrName);
```

For multiple selected options use `getAllSelectedOptions()`

```
List<WebElement> selectedItems = select.getAllSelectedOptions();
```

Comment: Thanks. This works exactly what i need. I learnt this concept today.